# CsvHelper: Map and references are not found in the current context

Tags: c#, csvhelper

[These are the errors I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phr1w.png)

I have two nested objects that I want to write out to a csv file for later reading. I went through online documentation for CsvHelper library and other posts and tried to write classmap definitions but I am getting below errors:

THe word "Map" does not exist in the current context

The word "References" does not exist in the current context

How can I get rid of these erros? I don't see Map or References in the intellisense. I am unsing csvhelper library, it is installed and I can write normal lines to csv files. So it is working but some parts of the library are not working!?

I tried to code my objects and mapclass exactly as what is described here:
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/244

here is my code. I have a list containing objects of type "Channel"; each channel object contains a list of sections with type "section". I need to write out all channels and all sections of each channel out to csv file for future reading. Map and references words are highlighted in red with the errors.

```
    public sealed class SectionDefinitionMap : CsvClassMap<Section>
    {
        public SectionDefinitionMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Name).Name("Section.Name");

        }
    }


    public sealed class ChannelDefinitionMap : CsvClassMap<Channel>
    {
        public ChannelDefinitionMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Name).Name("Channel.Name");
            References<SectionDefinitionMap>(m => m.Section);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are probably missing a **project reference** to the library. Try to add it using **NuGet**

Comment: post some example code

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, CsvHelper exists in the project references...looking int he libray, I may have to use membermap....will try that now,

Comment: it's not working. please help!

Comment: `STG.CsvClassMap`? Do you have your own class named `CsvClassMap`, in addition to the one in `CsvHelper`? In that case you are getting a conflict and inheriting from your class, which does not contain a `Map` or `References` method

Comment: I dont have my own class with the same name but I was getting that error. Now it is gone, after reopening the project. :-/

Answer (score 0):

`CsvClassMap` is renamed to `ClassMap` in the newer version of CsvHelper. It is located in the `CsvHelper.Configuration` namespace.